# How store a function in a MongoDb document, and then read it from there and call it?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want store function in MongoDb document.
If i right , that can do like this:

```
collection.insertOne({ name: 'New', calculate: a => console.log(a) }, { serializeFunctions: true });
```

or:

```
const { Code } = require('mongodb');
collection.insertOne({ name: 'New', calculate: new Code(a => { console.log(a) }) });
```

as a result, we get a property with the datatype Code

```
{ name: "New", calculate: Code('a => { console.log(a); }', undefined)}
```

How work with it later.... how read this function from MongoDb and call it ???

i not undurstood how work with BSON

Thanks....

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/store-javascript-function-on-server/

Comment: Thanks . I read this documentation. I apologize, but I want to save the function in a property, and not as an independent document.  Also, nothing is said here how to work with the datatype Code.